# SSRS Export to Excel issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, cell, export-to-excel

I am having report in SSRS with two cell merged into one cell. While exporting this report to excel,
it shows me two different cells instead of merged one. The first cell is having value while other is blank. Kindly suggest solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Other report elements above or below your merged cell can cause what you are seeing.  Make sure that any other tables or text areas on the page have have line up with the start/stop points of your columns on the table with the merged cells.

For example, if you have another table or text title that doesn't line up with one of your columns, Excel forces in an extra blank column.  If you temporarily remove anything other than your table with the problem, you may see that it suddenly works.

Another trick is to use points as the unit of measure when specifying widths and heights.  When you export to Excel, any measurements in inches are converted to points.  Sometimes it ends up with partial points resulting in unexpected behavior.  For details about the points measurements see - [Microsoft's explanation here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2777223)